# Can I make Windows recognize an NTFS partition on the same device as Linux partitions?

Tags: linux-mint, partitioning, windows, multi-boot

I'm running Linux Mint 20.2 on a removable USB4 storage device alongside a Windows 10 NVMe drive, so not explicitly a 'dual boot' but close enough (and fast enough) for my use case. The storage device was 250GB, but I partitioned Mint so that its boot partition plus root filesystem only take up a little over 200GB with the intent of creating a shared NTFS partition on the device to easily transfer files between Windows and Linux (as my Windows install is encrypted with BitLocker).

However, after returning to Windows, I am unable to see my storage device through any means, before and after creating an ~25GB NTFS partition with GParted. diskpart, Disk Management, and a third party tool claiming to recognize ext4 cannot see the drive at all. Linux, my UEFI firmware, and live USBs all recognize the device (the last is very surprising since it's super new hardware) and all its partitions. I would assume this is because Windows is skipping over the boot partition and, upon seeing a file system it does not natively recognize in the ext4 system partition, discarding the device.

If this is the problem, I could mitigate it by shuffling partitions around on my storage device (I'm able to safely delete the shared partition and move the others before recreating), but I'm worried about that affecting my ability to boot from the drive as the boot partition is no longer the first partition (I cannot find any resources on whether that matters). Would the hardware still recognize it as a boot drive if the first partition is NTFS and the second partition is FAT EFI, and is this even the right approach to what I want to do?

If it helps, I have my bootloaders set up so that grub is currently only installed on the external storage device as the first partition, and its files created in my Windows drive's boot partition are removed (as they were created due to a bug in the LM installer and just caused problems overall).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Output of my NTFS sector read with `sudo file -s /dev/sda3`:

```
/dev/sda3: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x52+2, OEM-ID "NTFS    ", sectors/cluster 8, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 63, heads 255, hidden sectors 400224256, dos < 4.0 BootSector (0x80), FAT (1Y bit by descriptor); NTFS, sectors/track 63, sectors 52428799, $MFT start cluster 4, $MFTMirror start cluster 3276799, bytes/RecordSegment 2^(-1*246), clusters/index block 1, serial number 06a1e84a36e6810c3
```

EDIT 2: Disk Management after plugging and unplugging the Linux boot drive and rescanning disks, not showing the Linux drive:
[image: Disk Management]

Comment: I think there is something 'funny' with your NTFS partition, otherwise an up to date Windows 10 system should see it. Early Windows 10 versions and previous Windows versions saw only one partition on USB drives, the first one in the partition table, but this is no longer the case with current versions of Windows 10 (and 11). -- If you have time and an extra USB drive, you can try with a persistent live Linux Mint system made by [mkusb-dus](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) - It creates an NTFS 'usbdata' partition by default, and works not only with pendrives, but also HDDs and SSDs.

Comment: Please post the output of your "NTFS" partition: `sudo file -s /dev/$partition` e.g. `/dev/nvme0n1p5`. I'm almost sure you did not create an NTFS partition but something else entirely. Or, you're using some weird partitioning scheme, i.e. LVM which Windows does **not** support.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I've added the output to my question. The partitioning scheme is gpt when I check in GParted. I wasn't asked to specify one in install, so that was determined automatically.

Comment: `file -s` output looks good. Please post a screenshot of your Disk Management after rebooting to Windows.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov added, doesn’t show the drive.

Comment: The Disk Management should at the very least show the disk device even if the content was unknown, to enable repartitioning/reformatting. I think the problem might be that Windows would need to detect the USB4 storage device, which might require an equivalent of PCIe hotplugging, which might need special drivers. Does the Windows Device Management show any devices with an exclamation mark, or does it detect the USB4 NVMe device successfully as a storage device?

Comment: @telcoM The USB4 device is not an NVMe device, its's just a USB-C storage device that uses USB4. It was visible from Windows before I installed Linux on it so I know I already have the drivers, but now it is completely invisible only to WIndows after I've installed Linux on it. There is one device with an exclamation mark, `Intel(R) USB 3.10 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.20 (Microsoft)`, and it has a duplicate right below it with no exclamation mark.

Comment: Windows does not show your drive whatever it is. It's not about partitions, it's about detection. Sorry, no idea what's happening. Try to delete the controller and search for new devices.

Comment: Also, in your question you state **"the Linux drive"**. There's no such thing, storage devices do **not** belong to particular OSes. They are universal and work via certain interfaces (ATAPI, ATA, SATA, SCSI, USB, etc.).

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Deleting and searching for new devices worked, I'm able to see the NTFS partition! Something must have gone wrong with it while I was messing around with installs (I must have formatted that drive, reinstalled Mint, and deleted the ubuntu folder in my Windows boot partition at least 10 times haha). Please add this as an answer!
Also, I was just saying 'the linux drive' as shorthand for 'my USB4 storage device which Linux Mint is installed to.' Likewise, my NVMe drive is 'the windows drive'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reasons the USB controller, `Intel(R) USB 3.10 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.20 (Microsoft)` in Windows 10 has broken for the OP.

Please try to delete it in Device Manager and search for new devices.

This question belongs to superuser.com but we've managed to resolve it here :-)